# Conditional merging in Python3

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.x, merge

I am trying to merge variables to keys existing in a dictionary.
Here are the rules:

> 1. If key already exists, then increment the value counter by one.
> 2. If partial match to key exists:
>      a. If variable length is smaller than key but re.search is not None, increment the value counter by one
>      b. If variable length is larger than key and re.search is not None, replace key by variable and increment counter by one
> 3. If variable exists after this but still has no match in dictionary, add variable to dictionary

I have been able to accomplish 1, 2a and 2b but I am not sure how to add 3.  Any help/suggesstions will be appreciated.
Here is the script in its present form:  I would also like to see "turtle" in the Dict.

```
Animals = ["phant", "eleph", "tiger", "turtle", "zebra", "ostrich"]
Dict = {"horse":1, "elephant":1, "iger":1, "ostrich":1}

for name in Animals:
     if name in Dict:
             Dict[name]=Dict[name]+1
     else:
             for key, val in Dict.items():
                     if len(name) < len(key):
                             m = re.search (name, key)
                             if m != None:
                                     print ("Found match!", name)
                                     Dict[key] = Dict[key] + 1
                                     break
                     elif len(name) > len(key):
                              m = re.search (key, name)
                              if m != None:
                                     print ("Found match!", name)
                                     Dict[name] = Dict.pop(key) + 1
                                     Dict[name] = Dict[name] + 1
                                     break
```

Comment: Why oh why are you mixing indentation levels? Are you mixing tabs and spaces? And (to solve the problem you're inquiring about), how about a plain old `else`?

Comment: Add a flag `found` which is initially `False` and set to `True` whenever a match happens. At the end of the `for` loop, see if `found` is `False` and then add key to dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to describe case #3 after looking at the code is "if neither of the `break` statements were executed".  You can handle this case by putting an `else` statement after the `for` loop.  The code within this block will only be executed if the `for` loop ran to completion (or in other words, there was no `break` statement run within the loop):

```
Animals = ["phant", "eleph", "tiger", "turtle", "zebra", "ostrich"]
Dict = {"horse":1, "elephant":1, "iger":1, "ostrich":1}

for name in Animals:
    if name in Dict:
        Dict[name]=Dict[name]+1
    else:
        for key, val in Dict.items():
            if len(name) < len(key):
                m = re.search (name, key)
                if m != None:
                    print ("Found match!", name)
                    Dict[key] = Dict[key] + 1
                    break
            elif len(name) > len(key):
                m = re.search (key, name)
                if m != None:
                    print ("Found match!", name)
                    Dict[name] = Dict.pop(key) + 1
                    Dict[name] = Dict[name] + 1
                    break
        else:                 # this line and the one below it are new
            Dict[name] = 1
```

Comment: Have you tried running it?  It does exactly what the OP is asking for, `"turtle"` is included in `Dict` at the end and everything else is the same as before.

Comment: Thank you F.J. Glad to see there are many viable options.  I am relatively new to python, but enjoying it a lot!

Comment: @F.J  You are absolutely right.  I didn't notice all "positive" cases ended in "break".  Sorry for that. +1

Answer (score 0):

```
for name in Animals:
    if name in Dict:
        Dict[name]=Dict[name]+1
    else:
        found= False
        for key, val in Dict.items():
            if len(name) < len(key):
                m = re.search (name, key)
                if m != None:
                    print ("Found match!", name)
                    Dict[key] = Dict[key] + 1
                    found= True
                    break
            elif len(name) > len(key):
                m = re.search (key, name)
                if m != None:
                    print ("Found match!", name)
                    Dict[name] = Dict.pop(key) + 1
                    found= True
                    break
        if not found
            Dict[name] = 1
```

I'd prefer the following, though:

```
for name in Animals:
    if name in Dict:
        Dict[name]=Dict[name]+1
    else:
        found= False
        for key, val in Dict.items():
            m = re.search (name, key)
            if m != None:
                print ("Found match!", name)
                if len(name) < len(key):
                    Dict[key] = Dict[key] + 1
                else
                    Dict[name] = Dict.pop(key) + 1
                found= True
                break
        if not found
            Dict[name] = 1
```

Comment: Thank you!  That worked perfect.  Sorry about the lab space problem in my code.  I was using Kate and it sometimes changes spaces to tabs!

Comment: @RaviKumar  Check the second one.  Is slightly shorter, but also easier to maintain (less repetition).

Comment: Thank you, the longer script works but the shorter one fails to merge tiger and iger.  I am assuming because re.search searches name in key and since existing key(iger) is shorter, tiger is kept separate.